# Extend time to comment & commenting on another user's question

Tags: feature-request

1. **Extend time to comment:** Any possibility to extending time to edit a comment? I find that as I am writing, a brainstorm or correction comes that needs review before updating comment. If original is incorrect and unable to edit or delete then it gets posted nonetheless creating possible confusion or unnecessary further comments for correction. Let's try to keep the chit-chat down to a minimum.
2. **Commenting on another user's question:** There is a restriction on making comments to another user's question. It appears to force a new "Answer" which is not necessarily correct in the case of wanting to add more clarification to the existing thread. If the "Answer" function is meant for the same thing then it should be made clear to all participants this is desired.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with point 1, but you can delete comments after the edit time elapses (no idea for how long, however)

As to point 2, you can comment on the question, but you have to have a rep of 50 to do so.  This (I assume) is to prevent noobs from over commenting.  I'm not there yet, but I could understand why as the community grows and more people can do so...

Comment: This really prohibits all chances of getting one's question answered in a timely fashion. We're all coming over from the CiviCRM forums. There has to be some expectation that ample back and forth to get support will work. Otherwise, this just sets up a gatekeeping system to keep the noobs whom we are trying to help get the help they need so they aren't noobs anymore. Anything else is pure passive-aggressiveness and selfishness to keep new users away. Don't we want to welcome people to the CiviCRM community and not piss them off so they will go away? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm a noob myself - this has felt more welcoming than being told if I can't code it then to pay for it to be done.  For the most part, things are being answered quickly at the moment as well. Rarely have I felt the need to comment on someone else's question. If I did, I'd include the question with my first stab at the answer. It keeps noobs from sidetracking a question instead of starting their own - a good thing in my book.

Answer (score 1):

Civi folks didn't come up with this. The rules are the same for all SE sites and for the most part I think they are with good reason. I'm still on the fence about the prohibition on commenting, but I can see the argument for not wanting people to misuse it.

The nice thing about being new here is that you won't have noob status for very long. Post one good question or one decent answer, and watch your rep score shoot upwards.

Comment: Maybe not but you chose to use a system that has these policies. Just sayin'. But, despite the housekeeping it just feels like gameplaying and gatekeeping. There are plenty of people who do not want to participate deeply but really need to get quick answers and to have to perform any hurdles while their business is affected is not a good way to deliver community tech support. More people leave vendors just because of less than adequate or difficulty accessing tech support. Just my opinion and experience having been in tech support for 30 years.

Comment: Point taken, and here's a counterpoint: this is the *free* support channel for CiviCRM. And I have to say it's providing extremely good value for that price point. But there are also many paid support options available for Civi that offer things like 24-hr emergency hotlines, guaranteed service, etc. If you find that this free support is inadequate to your needs, consider one of those.

Answer (score 0):

As you gain reputation you earn more content cration and editing privileges: see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges